# Failed to create Maven Project for selenium automation

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation

**Error stack:**

> Error:   Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Failed to parse
>   plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7
>   (C:\Users\lenovo.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-deploy-plugin\2.7\maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.jar):
>   invalid LOC header (bad signature)

**Maven commands used :**

```
C:\Users\lenovo>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=Projecturl -DartifactId=ProjectName -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when a jar in our local Maven repo is corrupt, then we'll see the error:

> invalid LOC header (bad signature)

A quick-fix for the error is to delete the whole Maven local repository and build the project again:

Try removing the content of the following folder:

```
C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository
```

Then right click your project in Eclipse or Any IDE, select Maven, Update Project, check on Force Update of Snapshots/Releases.

OR

you can also  try

```
mvn clean install
```